# jQuery get parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I am clicking a button inside this div and trying to retrieve the text from cockTailTitle. I have been unsuccessful with this type of query:

(inside of backbone)

```
this.$(e.currentTarget).parent().find('.cocktailTitle').text()
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
<div class="cocktailRecipeItem large-8 medium-8 small-12 large-centered medium-centered small-centered columns">
    <ul>
        <li class="cocktailImage">{{img}}</li>
        <li class="cocktailTitle">{{name}}</li>
        <li class="cocktailDescription">{{description}}</li>
        <li class="cocktailServing">makes {{servings}} servings</li>
        <li><span class="titleRecipe">Ingredients: </span>{{ingredients}}</li>
        <li><span class="titleRecipe">Recipe:</span> {{directions}}</li>
    </ul>
   <div class="large-8 medium-8 small-10 large-centered medium-centered small-centered columns"> <button class="recipeButton">Save Item</button><button class="recipeButton">Share!</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **[.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)** here since `.parent()` only get the parent `div` of your button but the `.cocktailTitle` is the children of the `ul` which is the immediate previous sibling of your button parent div:

```
this.$(e.currentTarget).parent().prev().find('.cocktailTitle').text()
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! should have asked earlier.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need `closest()` also instead of `this` and `$(e.currentTarget)`, you can simply use `$(this)` to refer to event source i.e. button being clicked.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xDVx4/)**

```
$(this).closest('.cocktailRecipeItem ').find('.cocktailTitle').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closest` method.

```
  $(this).closest('.cocktailRecipeItem').find('.cocktailTitle').text();
```